# Change the amount of cards (Sencha Touch Carousel)

Tags: sencha-touch, carousel

We're currently working with the Sencha Touch Carousel, and we got following problem. We haven't seen any easy way to show more than 3 cards / images (default option). The code looks like this

```
var gallery = new Ext.Carousel({
cls: 'galleryimage',
xtype: 'carousel',
height: '60px',
width: '65px',
items: [{
    html: '<img src="static/images/gallery/ex2.jpg" />',
    cls: 'image',
},
{
    html: '<img src="static/images/gallery/ex2_2.jpg" />',
    cls: 'image',
},
{
    html: '<img src="static/images/gallery/ex2_3.jpg" />',
    cls: 'image',
},
{
    html: '<img src="static/images/gallery/ex2_4.jpg" />',
    cls: 'image',
},
{
    html: '<img src="static/images/gallery/ex2_5.jpg" />',
    cls: 'image',
}]
```

});

It's pretty disturbing that it isn't clearly documentated, since I think alot of people want to do that. I hope there is anyone who has got a really easy way, without having to change other .scss files.

/* EDIT */

Added this code to it:

```
    var gallerypanel = new Ext.Panel({
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        defaults: {
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [gallery]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a working example with 4 cards :

```
Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    icon: 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady: function() {
        // Create a Carousel of Items
        var carousel1 = new Ext.Carousel({
            defaults: {
                cls: 'card'
            },
            items: [
            {
                title: 'Tab 1',
                html: '1'
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: '2'
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 3',
                html: '3'
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 4',
                html: '4'
            }]
        });


        new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                flex: 1
            },
            items: [carousel1]
        });
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I added the "new Ext.Panel" block to the code, and it didn't help at all. There are 3 pictures like before. It's like your code, except for the fullscreen: true.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this problem ?